# simplify() has no effect

Tags: matlab, expression, symbolic-math, algebra, simplification

I used the following snippet to simplify an equation:

```
syms P Q R S T U V A B C D E F G X Y
simplify((X - A)^2 + (Y - B)^2 - (X - B)^2 - (Y + A)^2)
```

Which gives me the result:

```
2*B*X - 2*A*Y - 2*A*X - 2*B*Y
```

On the other hand,

```
simplify((X - A)^2 + (Y - B)^2 - (X - B)^2 - (Y + 2*A)^2)
```

gives the same result after just re-ordering:

```
(A - X)^2 - (B - X)^2 - (2*A + Y)^2 + (B - Y)^2
```

What changed between these two equations? Am I not using the function correctly?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean what changed? `A`->`2*A`

Comment: @AnderBiguri I understand that. I made the change lol. :D I meant what changed inside MATLAB that caused `simplify()` not to work?

Comment: @AnderBiguri I believe the underlying question is "why does such a minor change in the expression cause the result of simplify to be completely different".

Comment: Have you done it by hand? Is it simpler to expand the powers in the second case? (hint:it is not, you end up with many terms)

Comment: @AnderBiguri So, MATLAB only simplifies if the number of terms in final answer are less than initial answer?

Comment: @iKnowNothing you mean " MATLAB only simplifies if the result of the simplification is simpler?". Yes.

Comment: @AnderBiguri How does MATLAB determine what is simpler? :) I am adding another example to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [the documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/simplify.html#btrv5w6-1), you can increase the amount of simplification "steps" using:

```
simplify(expr,'Steps',nSteps); % e.g. nSteps = 50
```

You can also try [other functions](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/choose-function-to-rearrange-expression.html) (`combine`, `expand`, `factor`, ...) for rearranging an expression.

I have the Maple symbolic toolbox for MATLAB and I get different results than you:

```
>> syms P Q R S T U V A B C D E F G X Y
>> simplify((X - A)^2 + (Y - B)^2 - (X - B)^2 - (Y + A)^2)

ans =

                         (-2 X - 2 Y) A + 2 B (X - Y)

>> simplify((X - A)^2 + (Y - B)^2 - (X - B)^2 - (Y + 2*A)^2)

ans =     
                         2
                     -3 A  + (-2 X - 4 Y) A + 2 B (X - Y)
```

In conclusion - it works as expected, you should give other functions/tools a try.

Comment: Thanks @Dev-iL. :) I am an absolute beginner when it comes to using MATLAB. How can I install Maple Symbolic Toolbox? I have MATLAB 2015 Installed.

Comment: Well, when you install [Maple](https://www.maplesoft.com/index.aspx), it looks for a MATLAB installation on the local system and suggests you to install Maple integration. You can also install the toolbox later as explained [here](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/downloads/mtm1102_installation.aspx). You'll have to look into Maple-MATLAB version compatibility though (I just use the latest of both).

Answer (score 2):

```
(X - A)^2 + (Y - B)^2 - (X - B)^2 - (Y + A)^2
X^2 + A^2 - 2*A*X + Y^2 + B^2 - 2*Y*B - X^2 - B^2 + 2*X*B -Y^2 - A^2 + 2*Y*A
2*B*X - 2*A*Y - 2*A*X - 2*B*Y
```

Initial: 12 operations used to compute a number

Final: 12 operations used to compute a number

---

On the other hand:

```
(X - A)^2 + (Y - B)^2 - (X - B)^2 - (Y + 2*A)^2
X^2 + A^2 - 2*A*X + Y^2 + B^2 - 2*Y*B - X^2 - B^2 + 2*X*B -Y^2 - 4*A^2 + 4*Y*A
-3*A^2 + 2*B*X - 4*A*Y - 2*A*X - 2*B*Y
```

Initial: 13 operations used to compute a number

Final: 15 operations used to compute a number